# Mismatch between VS Code intellisense and TypeScript compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is it possible for VS Code to show errors that are not caught by the TypeScript compiler when both are using the same TypeScript version?

My VS Code installation is using TypeScript version 2.6.2. I see that intellisense detects an error `'Parameter ... implicitly has an 'any' type` in one of my  code files, but when I run the tsc compiler, there are no errors.

It seems this behavior suddenly started; One moment the code editor was clean, and then the next moment it has all these red lines underneath some lines.

[image: This is my VS Code editor]

Comment: Could be a `tslint` (code style) error, not a syntax error. Do you have a `tslint.json` in your project?

Comment: @cubrr No I do not have a tslint.json in my project

Comment: I assume vscode uses the `tsconfig.json` file. If your `tsc` process reads the `tsconfig.build.json` instead you might want to look at a mismatch of the `"noImplicitAny"` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Comment: Yes, I think it was a mismatch between the tsconfig.json and the tsconfig.build.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a mismatch between the tsconfig.json and the tsconfig.build.json